# Core Data Error: "Can't find model for source store"

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, core-data, migration

I just deleted an attribute of my entity inside CoreData and after that this error appears:

> 2016-02-02 21:37:54.499 toRep_Management[32110:4679391] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:XML configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/Tom/Library/Application%20Support/de.toEducate.toRep_Management/CocoaAppCD.storedata options:{
>       NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
>       NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
>   } ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed object model." UserInfo={URL=file:///Users/Tom/Library/Application%20Support/de.toEducate.toRep_Management/CocoaAppCD.storedata, metadata={type = immutable dict, count = 6,
>   entries =>
>       0 : {contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = {contents = "A3FD787E-495C-493D-A3B9-2E7F7925EF7C"}
>       3 : {contents = "NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = (
>       ""
>   )
>       4 : {contents = "NSStoreType"} = {contents = "XML"}
>       10 : {contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = {value = +641, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
>       11 : {contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = {type = mutable dict, count = 1,
>   entries =>
>       0 : Notice = {length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xd22eaaf9bb53e406e8914544584e0e72 ... 0899bacb36b735bd}
>   }
>   12 : {contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} = {value = +3, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
>   }
>   , reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary {
>       URL = "file:///Users/Tom/Library/Application%20Support/de.toEducate.toRep_Management/CocoaAppCD.storedata";
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 641;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Notice = ;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = XML;
>           NSStoreUUID = "A3FD787E-495C-493D-A3B9-2E7F7925EF7C";
>       };
>       reason = "Can't find model for source store";
>   }
>   2016-02-02 21:37:54.499 toRep_Management[32110:4679391] CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
>       Notice = <2465d170 cdc5f276 8e769b4d 25c03a0d 8efb193b 6707ab4d 46419c42 17733df1>;
>   }

I thought I implemented a lightweight migration correctly but now I´m not sure anymore.

My AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "de.toEducate.toRep_Management" in the user's Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let appSupportURL = urls[urls.count - 1]
    return appSupportURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("de.toEducate.toRep_Management")
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("toRep_Management", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. (The directory for the store is created, if necessary.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var failError: NSError? = nil
    var shouldFail = false
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    // Make sure the application files directory is there
    do {
        let properties = try self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.resourceValuesForKeys([NSURLIsDirectoryKey])
        if !properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey]!.boolValue {
            failureReason = "Expected a folder to store application data, found a file \(self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.path)."
            shouldFail = true
        }
    } catch  {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        if nserror.code == NSFileReadNoSuchFileError {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                failError = nserror
            }
        } else {
            failError = nserror
        }
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = nil
    let migrateOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

    if failError == nil {
        coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CocoaAppCD.storedata")
        do {
            try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSXMLStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: migrateOptions)
        } catch {
            failError = error as NSError
        }
    }

    if shouldFail || (failError != nil) {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        if failError != nil {
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = failError
        }
        let error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().presentError(error)
        abort()
    } else {
        return coordinator!
    }
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving and Undo support

@IBAction func saveAction(sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Performs the save action for the application, which is to send the save: message to the application's managed object context. Any encountered errors are presented to the user.
    if !managedObjectContext.commitEditing() {
        NSLog("\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)) unable to commit editing before saving")
    }
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSApplication.sharedApplication().presentError(nserror)
        }
    }
}

func windowWillReturnUndoManager(window: NSWindow) -> NSUndoManager? {
    // Returns the NSUndoManager for the application. In this case, the manager returned is that of the managed object context for the application.
    return managedObjectContext.undoManager
}

func applicationShouldTerminate(sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
    // Save changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

    if !managedObjectContext.commitEditing() {
        NSLog("\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)) unable to commit editing to terminate")
        return .TerminateCancel
    }

    if !managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        return .TerminateNow
    }

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        // Customize this code block to include application-specific recovery steps.
        let result = sender.presentError(nserror)
        if (result) {
            return .TerminateCancel
        }

        let question = NSLocalizedString("Could not save changes while quitting. Quit anyway?", comment: "Quit without saves error question message")
        let info = NSLocalizedString("Quitting now will lose any changes you have made since the last successful save", comment: "Quit without saves error question info");
        let quitButton = NSLocalizedString("Quit anyway", comment: "Quit anyway button title")
        let cancelButton = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button title")
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = question
        alert.informativeText = info
        alert.addButtonWithTitle(quitButton)
        alert.addButtonWithTitle(cancelButton)

        let answer = alert.runModal()
        if answer == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {
            return .TerminateCancel
        }
    }
    // If we got here, it is time to quit.
    return .TerminateNow
}
```

Could anybody help with the error and how can I handle this in future with a better migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Can't find model for source store" means that you're trying to do a model migration but that Core Data can't find the old version of the data model. For migration to work, you need to have both the old version and the new version. The error suggests that you only have the new version.

When you're going to change a data model and migrate data, you need to create a new version of the model in your project. You'd do this by selecting the model file in Xcode and using "Editor" menu --> "Add Model Version". Then you'd make your changes to the new version while leaving the old one in place.

You need to restore the old model. The best way to do that is to just look back through your SCM (git, probably) commits and get it.

Comment: Thanks, what I did is just remove the app from the simulator and rebuild. its work :D.

Comment: @FarrasDoko Removing the app does not resolve the main issue. Removing clears out the Store and recreate based on your new model. When your app is already live, you cannot ask the users to delete the App. You need a proper Core Data migration for that case

Comment: @user121095 yes, in my case I changed the data type of an entry (attribute) of entity, and that was bad. I should add new attribute with new data type.